# How to restrict text field symbols in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I am trying to restrict symbols (`!@#$%^&*()_+`, etc) in a text field. The application I am working on is using custom directives to generate text fields and I am not very familiar with it. I tried to implement the same by referring [How to restrict special characters in AngularJS textbox [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062276/how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-angularjs-textbox)
 but was not able to resolve my issue. I will attach all 
the related files below so that you will understand how framework is implemented.

I am trying to add the pattern restriction to a username form field. Please find the code below.

- [Form.js](https://paste2.org/hE7kGWB1)
- [Formusername.html](https://paste2.org/bJA2JFpe)

If we open the Element tab in Developer Tools, we will be able to see the directive name added to the input field as an attribute. I will copy the element tag from the developer window to show you the same:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" name="name" ng-keyup="onkeyup({e : $event})" ng-blur="onblur({e : $event})" ng-model="nameModel" value="" placeholder="" class="form-control lvp-form-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="" no-special-char="">
```

As you can see, `no-special-char=""` was added to the input field.

I am a fresher and still learning AngularJS. I am not familier with directives as well. Can anyone point out the mistake I am doing here and provide a solution? Also, if you think there's a better way to achieve this, please let me know the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-pattern like ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"

Comment: But that will only create a validation error, correct? I want to restrict the symbols from getting entered in to the text field instead.

Comment: @Phoenix u should try creating custom directive with a function to check input characters